# Python-Reading the contents inside NFC tag

Tags: python, nfc

I'm currently trying to read the content(typically an integer) in a NFC tag(not Mifare) which is written by myself on raspberry pi running on python 2.7 and i have totally no clue on how to extract the particular "variable" using python script(probably explorenfc-basic could help???) as I'm trying to use the integer read from the NFC tag to perform some tasks

I have Explore-NFC installed and working fine and the following was the output obtained (integer 1) from my tag after running explorenfc-basic

```
    Waiting for tag or device...
    on_name_lost(): :org.neardal
    Found record /org/neard/nfc0/tag0/record0
    Record type:    Text
    URI:
    Title:  1
    Action:
    Language:       en
    Encoding:       UTF-8
    Tag found
    ISO14443A ATQA:         4400
    ISO14443A SAK:  00
    ISO14443A UID:  04F49D2AFE3280
```

Been searching online for hours and no hope still.. Any help would be nice :)

Comment: Show some sample input and expected output.

Comment: "Title: 1" the "1" is the integer that I have wrote into the tag using my smartphone I believe. Any idea how do I extract the info out?

Comment: Still very confusing, please update your answer by example input/output and code you've tried.